# Sound button not working? COCOS2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I tried this code it didn't work, I want the button to play sound when it is clicked.

```
-(void)starButtonsound:(id)sender
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"fire_truck_1.wav"];
}
```

In init

```
starMenuItemsound = [CCMenuItemImage
                    itemWithNormalImage:@"play.png" selectedImage:@"play.png"
                    target:self selector:@selector(starButtonsound:)];
starMenuItemsound.position = ccp(525, 500);
[self addChild:starMenuItemsound z: 4];
starMenuItemsound.scale = 0.75;
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: need more info. what exactly is it doing wrong?

Comment: could you show the logs from the console ?

Comment: looks like a tag for cocosDenshion is missing on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in init

```
{
  // Using SpriteSheet ? Use spriteWithSpriteFrameName in place of spriteWithFile
       CCSprite *spriteNormal   = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"play.png"];
       CCSprite *spriteSelected   = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"play.png"];
       ccColor3B color = {128,128,128};
       spriteSelected.color = color;

       starMenuItemsound = [CCMenuItemImage
                        itemWithNormalSprite: spriteNormal selectedImage: spriteSelected
                        target:self selector:@selector(starButtonsound:)];
       starMenuItemsound.position = ccp(525, 500);
       starMenuItemsound.scale = 0.75;

       CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: starMenuItemsound, nil];
       menu.position = ccp(0.0f,0.0f);
       [self addChild: menu z:4];
  }
```

Call Function:

```
-(void) starButtonsound:(id)sender
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:1.0f]; //Do this in init method
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"fire_truck_1.wav"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A) [Set a breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW38) - essential knowledge for any programmer.

B) The CCMenuItemImage selector does not take an argument. Remove the colon from `@selector(startButtonSound)` and change the method to this:

```
-(void)starButtonsound
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"fire_truck_1.wav"];
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to make a difference..

    -(void)starButtonsound
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"fire_truck_1.wav"];
}



  
       starMenuItemsound = [CCMenuItemImage
                        itemWithNormalImage:@"play.png" selectedImage:@"play.png"
                        target:self selector:@selector(starButtonsound)];
        starMenuItemsound.position = ccp(525, 500);
      //CCMenu *starMenusound = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
       [self addChild:starMenuItemsound z: 4];
      starMenuItemsound.scale = 0.75;
        

I am confused..

Answer (score 0):

Some reported that this is a solution: turning sound off and on again (no joke)

```
[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].muted = YES;
[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].muted = NO;
```